# Info on C/C++ API/Library for efficient sound output when pressing keyboard keys

Tags: audio, background-process

I want to create a Windows Application (using the C/C++) for personal use that runs in background and which plays sounds when I press keys on the keyboard. The following is an example of the type of application I want to make:

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Shell-Replacements/Tiper.shtml

The reason I'm interested in creating my own version is that I want to make it more extensible than the current examples that I have found. For example, the Tiper application that I mentioned above allows one to set sounds for the following:

- sound of typing letters and numbers (the same sound for every letter & number)
- sound of typing "Enter" key
- sound of typing "Backspace" key
- sound of typing "space" key
- sound of typing keys like "Tab", "Home", "PgUp" & etc

This is OK. However, I would like to create a version of this type of application that allows:

- Setting different sounds for every single key of the keyboard. That is, a different sound for 'A', a different sound for 'B', etc.
- Setting different sounds for combinations of keys. For example, setting a unique sound when pressing Ctrl+S.

**I'm interested in info about which Windows C/C++ API, library, functions, etc, which will give me the best possible performance for playback of the sound.** That is, the least possible delay between pressing a keyboard key and hearing the sound. These are the considerations to take into account about the properties of the final solution:

- The application will have lots of sound files loaded into ram; let say one for every key and desired key combination. So it could be about 150 different sound files. The computers that I'll be using have a least 8GB ram.
- The application only needs to run in Windows 7 and above.
- I type at about 60 words per minute, so sounds should be able to stack. That is, if I press 'A', and quickly press 'D', the 'A' sound should continue playing and not get cut off because 'D' is now playing. I reckon that about 5 sounds playing simultaneously should suffice.
- Suppose I should also take into consideration the speed at which keyboard 'keydown' events can be read. Though, I'm thinking that the standard way to grabbing this sort of info using the Windows API should be good enough.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: Based on my research, I won't be able to get the performance I'm looking, unless I go with something fullscreen.